# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used in a set state

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, setstate

To have a better view this is the  [image]

```
  void _addImage(c) async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image?.path);
    print(_imagePath?.split('/').last);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        String _imagePath = attachments.add(image.path);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

It was invalid, it was to render image uploaded name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like..

```
Future<void> _addImage(c) async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image?.path);
    print(_imagePath?.split('/').last);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        String _imagePath =  image!.path;
        attachments.add(_imagePath);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello I tried the _addImage function when clicking a button to upload an image that doesn't work. Thanks for your prompt response and God bless

Comment: If you are having `_imagePath` as a field variable then `String _imagePath =  image!.path;` -> `_imagePath =  image!.path;`

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like this:

```dart
Future<void> _addImage(c) async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image?.path);
    print(_imagePath?.split('/').last);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        attachments.add(image!.path); 
        //removed _imagePath variable because it was being used just to carry
        //the value of image!.path 
        //if you want to use it as a global variable please define it outside
        //the function scope
        // String imagePath = "";
        // _addImage(c){setState((){imagePath = image!.path;});}
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Couple of things I noticed in this function:

1. `c` parameter is never used
2. `_imagePath?.split('/').last` could break depending upon what OS you run it on

Answer (score 0):

**

### This worked out

**

```
Future<void> _addImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image?.path);
    if (image != null) {
      setState(() {
        String _imagePath = image!.path;
        attachments.add(_imagePath);
        imageName = [_imagePath.split('/').last];
        print(_imagePath.split('/').last);
      });
    }
  }
```